# regex in SAS - how to strip white spaces surrounding special characters?

Tags: regex, sas

For the address data, would anyone have any idea on how to strip white spaces around the special characters in the numeric bit of these records? For the third record, for example, I want to have "44/95" instead of "44 / 95".
The special characters I want to do this for all "/","-","|" and ",".
I am guessing that using regex is the best way but I can't think of how to do this.

```
data addresses1;
infile datalines ; 
input @1 address $35. ;
format address $50.;
datalines;                      
26 32-50 CENTRE DANDENONG ROAD
9 /93-95  DANDENONG ROAD EAST 
44 / 95 OUTER CRESCENT   
17| 21-25 PARKHILL DRIVE      
run;
```

I have tried something like the following code, but did not work. Can someone point me to the right direction?

```
data addresses2;
set addresses1;
format fixed_address fixed_address2 $255.;
address=strip(address);

fixed_address2=compbl(strip(prxchange("s/(?<=[\|.\(\)\{\}\-\:\s\*\;\.\#\&\_\/\\]) +(?=\[\|.\(\)\{\}\-\:\s\*\;\.\#\&\_\/\\])/$1/",-1,strip(fixed_address))));

run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a RegEx for you, that should Work:

```
\S*( ?(?![/|,-])).*(?<![[/|,-])
```

It selects zero or more Non-Whitesspaces then a Space not followed by any of your characters, then one or more of any character, making sure the previous char is not any of your characters. It's not elegant and you will have to strip empty maches.

Comment: It seems to match all cases, which is great, but how would you replace the strings with the correct results?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know sas, I just made the regex for you.